# How to set a title for a CHM file?

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

My CHM file always opens with the title **Help** in the title bar and I want to change this.

I changed the Title property in HHP file, but that didn't help.

I also tried adding this to HHP:

```
[WINDOWS]
main="my-help-title"
```

but that didn't help either, help-window's title always stays **Help**.

How can I change the title? I'm opening the CHM from a Win Forms application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[options]  
Title="my-help-title"
```

See http://www.nongnu.org/chmspec/latest/INI.html for more options

If not, then it is probably the [windows] option, which look like this:

```
[WINDOWS]
main="Online Help","CHM-example.hhc","CHM-example.hhk","index.htm","index.htm",,,,,0x23520,275,0x1046,[317,243,947,683],0xB0000,,,,,,0
```

Comment: Nope, I already had that and tried writing the Title both with and without quotes and still nothing? :/

Comment: Still no change :/ I'm using HTML Help Workshop v. 4.74.8702.0 Maybe it's obsolete?

Comment: No idea what version I had. I pulled this from a project I also had the CHM of though, and it showed the title fine.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Help is not a Unicode application, and there is a risk of showing garbage characters if the primary language ID of the CHM does not match the primary language ID of the systems LCID (for example a KOR help title displayed on a Japanese OS). The caveat here is when the help title is compiled as English. English help titles can display their titlebar string on all operating systems since all of the code pages support English.

Unfortunately the check is too strict. Only the Primary Language ID should be checked, however HH also checks the Secondary Language ID causing say Portuguese (Brazil) help to display HTML Help on a Portuguese (Portugal) PC.

In the case of English help, in the past all help had to be set to English (US). This bug was fixed in HH 1.31? and now English (Australian) help for example will display correctly on all systems.

http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/hh-faq#TOC-Why-does-my-CHM-window-show-the-title-HTML-Help-instead-of-my-title-